# Why after every scan the result is little difference?

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

Android Studio 3.6, Firebase ML Kit.

I create Android app that need to scan images and extract text from it.
To do this I use Firebase ML Kit.

in my app/build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
        implementation "com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.5.0"
        implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

here my activity:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionText
private fun runDetector(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
        val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap!!)
        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().onDeviceTextRecognizer

        val result = detector.processImage(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { firebaseVisionText ->
                processTextResult(firebaseVisionText)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            }
    }

    private fun processTextResult(firebaseVisionText: FirebaseVisionText) {
        var detectedText = "\n"
        firebaseVisionText.textBlocks.forEach {         
            detectedText += it.text + "\n"
        }
        Debug.d(TAG, "processTextResult: detectedText_start\n")
        Debug.d(TAG, detectedText)
        Debug.d(TAG, "processTextResult: detectedText_end")
```

Here result after scan 3 time same image (with text):

1. "some company name
   C.F
   O081 0perator U1
   Latte
   1111111111111
   17.00 C
   17.00 C
   3.08 C
   1.000 X 17,00
   1.000 X 17.00
   1.060 X 3.08
   Latte
   dDte
   37 .00
   OAL
   TVA C 10.00%
   NUMERAR
   3.
   37
   36
   .00
   803 ART
   MUL TUMIM!!!
   183654
   23-12-2819
   15:14
   BON F ISCAL: 0131
   ZKe0682347
   Ser.
   N. Inr
   N
   F702822971"

2.

```
"some company name
C.F
C                            
F                            
9881                         
Latte                        
1111111111111
Operator 81                  
1.000 X 17.00                
1,008 X 17.00                
17.00 C                      
17.00 C                      
3.00 C                       
Latte                        
apte                         
1.060 X 3.08                 
31.86                        
UIAL                         
TVA C 10.00%                 
NUMERAR                      
B. .36                       
,00                          
ART                          
37                           
883                          
MUL TUMIM !                  
15:14                        
103654                       
BON FISCAL: 6131             
23-12-2819                   
ZKO0682347                   
Ser.N                        
N.Inr                        
F782022971"
```

3. "some company name
   F
   1111111111111
   o01 Operator 81
   Lotte
   1.808 X 17.00
   1.008 X 17.00
   1.060 x 3,08
   17.00 C
   17.00 C
   3.00 C
   Latte
   apte
   0AL
   NUME RAR
   37.00
4. .36
   .00
   803 ART
   VA C 10.00%
   37
   MUL TUMIM !!!
   103654
   23-12-2819
   15:14
   BON F ISCAL: 0131
   ZKO0602347
   Ser .N
   N. Inr
   F702022971"

As you can see after every scan **of the same image** I get difference result.

Questions:

- Is it possible to get same result after every scan?
- How to achieve the most identical result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the model ML Kit uses for its text extraction is deterministic: for the exact same input it should give the exact same output.

So most likely you're feeding it a slightly different image for each result, for example by feeding it images from your camera and moving that. Even if you move the camera ever so slightly, the image will be different, and so will be the text that ML Kit extracts.

I've always seen this behavior from these ML models. For example, Google Translate also is highly susceptible to subtle differences in its interpretation as you move the camera around slowly. So I doubt it's something you can tweak/configure about the model.

The two options I can think of is:

1. Train a custom model and see if you can get rid of the difference in output from similar images. I admit I'm a bit skeptical about the chances of this on general images, given the example I gave above. But it may be possible that you have a data set that has fewer small variations, or maybe even adding a pre-processing step.
2. Use a statistical OCR tool, which takes a completely different approach to detecting and recognizing text. I've used Abby in the past, which worked very accurately on scanned text. A few searches now hint that Tesseract might be a viable open-source alternative too.

Answer (score 0):

This because angel of camera not  the same at scanning and to check most identical results you must write complex code